# Answers to the questions I am interested or commenting?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments

There are questions asked on Stack Overflow which have yet to be answered. Sometimes I am facing the same problems, or I am interested in knowing the answers to these questions. For this I need to scroll down all questions one by one from the "**Questions**" part.

Is there any way to keep log of such questions in my own account so that I can see that question and answer from my own account?

Also how can I keep track of the answers (or discussions) of questions on which I have commented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the empty star under upvote/downvote buttons:

[image]

Then it'll be added to your profile and you can easily follow it:

[image]

Of course you can remove it again from your favorites by clicking on the filled star again to empty it.